How to implement reload-on-rss on mod_wsgi in Django?
In uwsgi, reload-on-rss helps to prevent the Django server from running into OOM. How do you implement reload-on-rss on mod_wsgi in Django? I want the Django server to reload after the server hits a specific memory.
